# Ruby on Rails - Neo4J Connection Refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, database-connection, neo4j.rb

I am writing a Ruby on Rails application and using a Neo4J database. I'm using the neo4j-core gem in order to integrate the two and I have a problem when connecting to the database.

The database is not located at the same server as the application so I needed to change some configuration. In application.rb file, I added the following code:

```
module Workspace
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Neo4j configuration
    config.neo4j.session_type = :server_db 
    config.neo4j.session_path = 'http://***.***.**.***:7474'
  end
end
```

I tried running the application after this and it was working. However, I then added the following in a controller in order to test the connection further:

```
module Api
    class CountriesController < ApplicationController
        def index
            Neo4j::Session.open(:server_db)

            # Get Coutnry Information
            @countryList = Neo4j::Session.query. ...
        end
    end
end
```

And if I try to run the application now, it's giving me the following connection error (on the line where I'm opening a Neo4J session):

```
connection refused: localhost:7474
```

Why is it trying to connect to the localhost even though in the configuration of Neo4J I specified the real IP of the database?

I'm super confused by this right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration is available in the [neo4jrb/neo4j](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j) gem, not in [neo4jrb/neo4j-core](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core). Try this instead:

```
Neo4j::Session.open :server_db, "http://your_ip:7474"
```